# rsyslogd: How to prevent logging in the /var/kern.log file and redirecting to another file?

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, logging, syslog, syslogd

I am trying to redirect iptables log to another file.
Based upon my reading on the net, I did the following:

In my iptables rule, I have rules like:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s ... -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables@@"
```

Then in the folder /etc/rsyslog.d, I created a file with the entries:

```
 :msg,contains,"iptables@@" /var/log/iptables.log
 & ~
```

I also tried to have a blank line between the above two lines.
I do get the iptables log entries now going to iptables.log file. But they ALSO go to /var/log/kern.log file. I want to suppress the later. How do I do this. I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: If you use **-j NFLOG  --nflog-group 1 --nflog-prefix "INext-EOF"**  You can redirect iptables via ulogd2.  You can direct it to text file, or even a mysql database.

Comment: Did you add your rule near the top of the config file above the entry for /var/log/kern.log?

Comment: @cybernard  Thanks. I tried the first suggestion as is and it did not work. Now it does not log in either /var/log/kern.log or in the specified log file. I guess I need to install ulogd2 and do some other config/edits? Will need to read but the direct logging in MySQL can be helpful.  As for the second suggestion, which "top of the config file" are you referring to? The entries specified above, made by me, refer to a separate file under /etc/rsyslog.d. There are no other entries in that file. This is suggested [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/348439/iptables-log-file-and-how-change-it).

Comment: For ulog you need **stack=log1:NFLOG,base1:BASE,ifi1:IFINDEX,ip2bin1:IP2BIN,mac2str1:HWHDR,mysql1:MYSQL** and you need to set the crendentials,db,table and etc in the ulogd.conf.  And create a properly structured table.  More later.

Comment: @cybernard For now I just want to avoid duplicating iptables log in the kernel log file.

Comment: Do you have a rsyslog.conf in the /etc folder not in the /etc/rsyslog.d folder?

Comment: BTW  The correct mysql db structure is in this file ./doc/mysql-ulogd2.sql.  mysql -u root -p <database name> <./doc/mysql-ulogd2.sql

Comment: @cybernard Yes. I have rsyslog.conf in /etc folder and NOT in /etc/rsyslog.d  folder. Also, I did not touch rsyslog.conf file.

Comment: You need to open that file and look for an entry pointing to **/var/log/kern.log**.  Move your rule above that rule.

Comment: @cybernard I renamed the file in /etc/rsyslog.d dealing with the mapping of the magic-string to file name. I have it now alphabetically named before the other files in that directory. It worked. Got clue from your suggestion "Move your rule above that rule." Thanks. I suggest you post this as an answer with all your other suggestions. It will surely be useful to others. I will accept it as now it logs only in the iptables log file and NOT in kern.log. Thanks for patiently responding to all issues along the way.

Comment: @cybernard  The other files in /etc/rsyslog.d are 20-ufw.conf and 50-default.conf. Renaming the file to 10-iptables.conf did it. It was earlier 70-iptables.conf.